# ¿Cómo podría hacer este trozo de código con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me gustaría poder pasar este trozo de código a jquery, pero me está danto problemas.
Si alguien me pudiese ayudar

```
document.querySelectorAll('.lista-items').forEach(item=> item.parentNode.removeChild(item));
```

hasta ahora lo que he intentado a hacer es esto

```
$(".lista-items").forEach(item=> item.parent().remove(item)); 
pero me sale error. me dice que forEach no es una funcion
```

Pretendo  eliminar los div que tengan dentro de otro div cuya class es lista-items. con javascript vanilla funciona, pero ya que estoy haciendo todo con jquery, me gustaría poder hacerlo con jquery .
la estructura del html sera la siguiente

```
<div id="lista-items" class="lista-items">
        <div><strong>2</strong> 3442323</div>
        <div><strong>2</strong> 34234</div>
        <div><strong>2</strong> 3422342554534</div>
        <div><strong>2</strong> 32344</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

No necesitas recorrer con un ciclo, solo necesitas obtener los hijos y eliminarlos con el método [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/). El selector `.lista-items > div` funciona así:

- `.lista-items` Especifica la clase a buscar
- `> div` Solo va a obtener los hijos directos con etiqueta `div`

```js
$('.lista-items > div').remove();
```

```css
/* Solo para comprobar que el padre se mantiene */
.lista-items {
    background:#ccc;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista-items" class="lista-items">
    <div><strong>2</strong> 3442323</div>
    <div><strong>2</strong> 34234</div>
    <div><strong>2</strong> 3422342554534</div>
    <div><strong>2</strong> 32344</div>
</div>

<div id="lista-items-2" class="lista-items">
    <div><strong>2</strong> 3442323</div>
    <div><strong>2</strong> 34234</div>
    <div><strong>2</strong> 3422342554534</div>
    <div><strong>2</strong> 32344</div>
</div>
```

En caso de que quieras usar ciclos, el método correcto es [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
$('.lista-items > div').each(index => $(this).remove());
```

Comment: anda gracias, esto de mezclar tecnologías xD